# Missing Apps, SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I would be very grateful if someone could answer a question for me. I would like to add several (built-in) apps like External Lists and Promoted links to my SharePoint 2013 Site collection. The issue is, when I select "Add an App" only a few apps appear in my site collection.

If I perform the same action under the Central Admin site I do have those apps available. My question is, how do I make all the apps available in a site collection other than Central Admin.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create team site and check external list is available in it??

Answer (score 6):

You need to activate the **Team Collaboration Lists** feature under **Manage Site Features** then you will have the ability to add External Lists.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for a long time, and could not figure it out until recently.  It was custom changes that were made to the master page template that prevented the list of apps from appearing.

To see if this is the case in your situation, go to your site settings, and temporarily change the master page template to one of the Defaults (like Seattle), and see if your app catalog re-appears.  If not, it is easy enough to turn your master page template back on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is my exact problem.  I proved that switching to a non custom master page brought the apps back.  Switching back to the custom master page makes the apps go away, and they must be custom.  Any clue how to allow the use of custom pages AND see the OOB apps?  Thanks~

Comment: @nicoleBC did you find a solution to this? I've just run into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If the feature is "Team Collaboration Lists" shows as "Active" - Toggle it!

Answer (score 0):

I know i am super late and the issue is fixed for SP Online (and certainly for onpremise),

but here is the solution if you have the same problem depicted by @Elohir and @nicoleBC:

http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html